# Can we apply no write permission on media folder in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, permissions, media

Hello Guys  i am using magento 1.8.1.0 version for the security point of view i want to put no write permission on media folder of magento.but it shows warning at the top of site. how to resolve this.is this folder permission feasible?.tell me what is best folder permission for media in magento.

Comment: Means what is recommended folder permission for media

Answer (score 1):

Without write permission on your media folder, you will **not be able to upload any file/image to your Magento website** so that is not recommended at all, except if you have a text only website.

You can find more details about the recommended permissions on a Magento installation here in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: @SarfarazAlam feel free to mark the question as answered so others can benefits from your question

Answer (score 0):

magento recommended permission settings will break your setup.
best folder permission for you can be absolutely different and depends on your webstack configuration.

to make it more secure you can add this to your apache config:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(skin|shell|lib|media)/.*\.php$">
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

this will 100% denied `.php` files execution in those folders.